# Why a lot of install options for different formulae are now gone in homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew

It seems for many homebrew packages/formulae previously available install options are mostly eliminated if not completely removed. Why is this? Is there a design change in homebrew to remove such flexibility?

Examples I've come across include: emacs, sqlite, curl, r, aspell, and many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*All* options of *all* formulae have been removed, because it was a burden on Homebrew maintainers and most of them weren’t used.

Instead, the default installation of each formula includes the most commonly used options.

From [Homebrew 2.0.0](https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/)’s changelog:

> Homebrew does not have any formulae with options in Homebrew/homebrew-core. Options will still be supported and encouraged by third-party taps. This change allows us to better focus on delivering binary packages rather than options. Formulae with options had to be built from source, could not be tested on our CI system and provided a disproportionate support burden on our volunteer maintainers.

You may also want to see Mike [McQuaid’s "*Homebrew 2.0.0*" presentation](https://fosdem.org/2019/schedule/event/homebrew_2/) at this year’s FOSDEM in which he talks a bit about that.

Comment: thanks, could you point to a source that shows how to enable install options with 3rd-party taps?

Comment: @skyork the [formula cookbook](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook) shows how to add options to a formula.